# Schema-validation: missing column in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

i'm using two persistence unit for copying one database to another with some additional columns using JPA.
and i'm getting this error
Schema-validation: missing column [ip] in table [copy.activity]

id class :

```
package model.local;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class LocalActivityId implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String ip;
    private long item;

    //GETTER SETTER CONSTRUCTOR

}
```

main bean:

```
package model.local;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name = "activity")
@Table(name ="activity", schema="resolvecopy")

@IdClass(LocalActivityId.class)
public class LocalActivityDetails {


    @Id
    private String ip;
    @Id
    private long item;
    private int type;
    private String description;
    //GETTER SETTER CONSTRUCTOR
}
```

Comment: Seems like [id] column is missing in your table [copy.activity]. Check in database if column is present or not

Comment: what database are you talking about, and on which platform? on some plaftorms, column names are case sensitive.

Comment: mysql5.7 windowsserver2016 @luca.vercelli

Comment: @Abhijeet it is present

Comment: In code you have mentioned schema as 'resolvecopy', and in error you are getting schema as 'copy'. which schema you checking?

Comment: yes I am through that bug@Abhijeet

Comment: in mysql on windows, column names are case insensitive, so that's not the problem